# Probability of correctly and faulty microprocessors

Tags: probability

In the group of $100$ microprocessors $10$ microprocessors are faulty. $5$ microprocessors are selected randomly. Find the probability that

a) All selected microprocessors are correctly

b) Exactly one microprocessor is faulty

c) At least one microprocessor is faulty

d) Maximum $3$ microprocessors are correctly

I tried

a) $\frac{\binom{90}{5}} {\binom{100}{5}}$ =0.5837

b) $\frac{\binom{10}{1}*\binom{90}{4}} {\binom{100}{5}}$ = 0.3393

c) ${\binom{90}{5}}+{\binom{90}{3}}*{\binom{10}{1}}+{\binom{90}{3}}*{\binom{10}{2}}+{\binom{90}{2}}*{\binom{10}{3}}+{\binom{90}{1}}*{\binom{10}{4}} {\binom{100}{5}}$

and all that divided with ${\binom{100}{5}}$

d) ${\binom{90}{1}})*{\binom{10}{4}}+ {\binom{90}{2}}*{\binom{10}{3}}+{\binom{90}{3}}*{\binom{100}{2}}$

and all that divided with ${\binom{100}{5}}$

Is this good way or I made mistake in reasoning?

Comment: (a) P(1st OK) = 90/100; P(1&2 OK) = P(1st OK) * P(2nd OK) = P(1st OK) * 89/99; P(1&2&3 OK) = P(1&2 OK) * 88/98; so on...  (b) P = 10/100 * 90/99 * ... * 87/96 * 5,  where 5 means number of choices of 1 out of 5 - the order does not matter.

Comment: At **d)** you have forgotten the probability that no processor is correctly. At the numerator the forgotten term is ${90 \choose 0}\cdot {10 \choose 5}$

Comment: At **c)** you can use the converse probability: $$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{\binom{90}{5}} {\binom{100}{5}}=1-0.5837=0.4163=41.63\%$$